# How to apply different CSS for mobile devices not just based on media width/height

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

I want to show different CSS styles for some elements just for mobile devices, phones and tablets, but media queries with different widths do not work quite good just because let's say my phone and my 17" laptop both have the same full HD resolution and modern tablets have resolution bigger than most desktop monitors have...

So I want to apply CSS styles for android, iphone/ipad, blackberry, windows mobile devices that are phones/tablets.

Are there any ways?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Resolution is not the same a pixel /device width.

Comment: in android you can check the device using '(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)'

Comment: @Paulie_D - if resolution is full HD, it means 1080p, or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is apply custom classes to the html element or body element using javascript by testing the userAgent.

see below:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery). So your solution would look something like this.

JS

```
/*
see the link above for other user agents. 
you could come up with a bit more sophisticate solution 
I'm sure but this would be a quick implementation.
*/
<script type="text/javascript">

//test if droid


if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('body').addClass('device_android');
}

</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>

//css styles for android

.device_android element #id .orclass {
    //some styles for android specific styling here
}

</style>
```

Keep in mind though this targets the general device this does not address the variation in os version and browser etc. which in many cases proves to be the cause of js and css bugs.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to use jquery

Answer (score 1):

Media queries can not only use width. You can also use the orientation and even the device pixel ratio. So if you address something like a retina display then you can write it  more or less as follows:

```
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width : xxx px) 
   and (max-device-width : xxx px) 
   and (orientation : landscape or portrait)
   and (min-resolution: xxx dpi){ 

   // your css goes here

}
```

Take a look for a webkit specific example [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)!

Comment: So, if i'll set min dpr 1.25, will that mean that more or less modern smartphones and tablets will be covered?

Comment: I do not get what you mean with **dpr 1.25**. Using the statement above you can e.g. address screens with a min-resolution of 200dpi. But this is only an indication that the actual screen is a Smartphone or Tablet. It might be also a new MacBook Pro with 220dpi resolution. To restrict it more device specific you then need to take into account the min-device-width, because a 15" MacBook Pro with 220dpi has a resolution of 2880x1800 and there is no Tablet/SmartPhone available with this values. To wrap up, you have to provide a lot of media types to accomplish your task.

Comment: forgive me for dpr :) i meant dpi/ppi. IF it was about targeting new devices with hight dpi, it would be quite easy to make that, but I also want to target some older ones too, but then some 1920x1080 13" netbooks have 170dpi, Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 has 149dpi, etc.. How to find some universal media query?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no universal guideline about media queries. You are responsible for the thinks you want to accomplish and media queries are the right tool for this. You can find some discussion about possible breakpoints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile?rq=1).

Comment: That disuccsion was more than 2 years ago. Things have changed drastically from then

Comment: Indeed! But that is not the point, the discussion there gives you the hints you need. Now you can use a combination of the filters to control the behaviour of your website at a very fine-granular level. But of course, this goes hand-in-hand with a lot of work on defining the media-types.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE ||
(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)
    ==          Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE ){
        System.out.println('In Tablet');
    }else {
        System.out.println('In Phone');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, while I don't yet fully understand what this javascript does, I would like the solution with just media queries if it is possible, and if not, then JS will come